# Turing reducibility of 2 versions of the satisfiability problem

Tags: reductions, satisfiability, discrete-mathematics

I need help with this problem.

> There are 2 versions of the satisfiability problem:
>
> [1] decision version: determine whether an arbitrary formula f is
>   satisfiable or not
>
> [2] search version: if an arbitrary formula f is satisfiable, return
>   an assignment of truth values to variables in the formula that makes f
>   satisfiable. if f is unsatisfiable, return NIL.
>
> Show that [2] is Turing reducible to [1].

I have to prove that the oracle algorithm of [1] entails that of [2] to say "[2] is Turing reducible to [1]".

I see that [2] is just the oracle algorithm of [1] since it discriminates the satisfiability of an arbitrary formula f.

Can this mean the oracle algorithm of [1] entails that of [2]? If can, what would be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any algorithm that decides the satisfiability of a formula can also be used to find an assignment for a satisfiable formula:

While not all variables are assigned:

- Pick a variable and choose value 0.
- If formula is no longer satisfiable, replace value with 1.